# Android emulator USB passthrough fails: " 'usb-host' is not a valid device model name"

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

When I try to use USB passthrough as described in https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/08/emulator-30024-canary.html,

`emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 -qemu -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=076B,productid=3821`

I get the error message `'usb-host' is not a valid device model name`. According to the Google link, USB passthrough should be supported from emulator version 30.0.24 and my emulator reports version 30.5.3.0 (build_id 7196367).

Has anyone succeeded in getting this to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No! Same with Android emulator version 30.5.4.0 (build_id 7243153).

If I look binary into the Linux version of the qemu emulator file,
I can still find the usb-host option. But it is totally left out
in the Windows Version.
So I guess Google must have switched the usb-host
support in Windows off.
Unfortunately the last Release Notes from the emulator is
from [30.4.5 (February 23, 2021)](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#other_new_features_and_enhancements)

Also I can't find any hint about this in the [android-review AOSP](https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/usb-host+qemu)
Don't know where else to look!?

[Update:]
I think I've found it, on the GitHub AOSP Mirror and [android-review AOSP](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/external/qemu/+/1611183).
From Erwin Jansen committed on 3 Mar:

[Revert "Enable usb host redirection for Windows"](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_external_qemu/commit/92ec8e5214f9c54130601e8007838e9169d4a514)

```
# Libusb support on windows is not what we would like it to be
LIBUSB_FLAGS="--disable-libusb --disable-usb-redir"
```

It looks like the USB Pass Through Feature on Windows was just too buggy.
So, If one would get back to [Version 30.5.2 (build_id 7175973)](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-7175973.zip) (Feb 27, 2021)
the usb-host will still be a valid device model name.
The DL was taking from a [Canary Channel](https://github.com/tadfisher/android-nixpkgs/blob/c4aa702506046c4015e626aa993065bbb5d0b469/channels/canary/default.nix).

But it looks like Google is still [working](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/external/qemu/+/1555478) on it...

[Update 10.12.21]
Since Emulator Version 31.1.4 google implemented some new features and tools
to pass USB through.
I couldn't find the [-list-usb](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/external/qemu/+/1761045/4) parameter with emulator -help, but it works
if you run:

```
emulator -list-usb
VID:PID 058f:6387 (Bus 1, Port 5.1.1)
        Manufacturer:
        Product:
        SerialNumber:   40A0FE0A
```

With this information, you can use the [-usb-passthrough](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/external/qemu/+/1761967/6/android/android-emu/android/help.c#2038) parameter
(-usb-passthrough vendorid=VID,productid=PID[,hostbus=BUS,hostport=PORT])

```
emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_4_API_31 -usb-passthrough vendorid=058f,productid=6387,hostbus=1,hostport=5.1.1
```

but it shows the error:

```
ERROR   | Cannot load Android USB Assistant Driver for USB device "vendorid=058f". USB pass-through might not work.
```

Again a new tool Google added, with the [prebuilt Windows drivers for USB passthrough](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/external/qemu/+/1786589/3) one could try it again. Downloadable directly from the [AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/refs/heads/emu-31-release/android/third_party/usbpassthrough-prebuilt-win32/) (tgz)

run as admin:

```
Install_Drivers.bat
```

```
Installing Android USB Assistant...
call Android_USB_Assistant_Install.bat
Microsoft PnP Utility

Processing inf :            Android_USB_Assistant.inf
Successfully installed the driver.
Driver package added successfully.
Published name :            oem89.inf


Total attempted:              1
Number successfully imported: 1

Installing Android Emulator USB Passthrough Assistance Driver

SERVICE_NAME: UsbAssist
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: UsbAssist
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
        PID                : 0
        FLAGS              :
```

But trying it again, still shows the same error.

[Update 13.12.21]
Now it is working. The correct syntax is with the **0x** and without
the usbhost and usbport keyword:

```
-usb-passthrough vendorid=0x058f,productid=0x6387
```

It still shows an error message:

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
```

And the Device is not recognized in the AVD,
but as soon as you root the AVD (Magisk Canary) with my script [rootAVD](https://github.com/newbit1/rootAVD) from Github
with the parameters **PATCHFSTAB GetUSBHPmodZ**

```
rootAVD.bat %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-32\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\ramdisk.img PATCHFSTAB GetUSBHPmodZ
```

and install my usbhostpermissions.zip Magisk Module, an USB drive will
appear as Drive system-wide and an USB Serial Device can be accessed
through a USB Serial Terminal Apk. The APK USB Device Info will also
now show the connected USB Devices. I will update my [XDA Guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-build-mod-avd-kernel-android-10-11-rootavd-magisk-usb-passthrough-linux-google-play-store-api.4212719/) asap
accordingly.

In order to pass more USB Devices through, just add another one behind the first i.e:

```
emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_4_API_32 -usb-passthrough vendorid=0x058f,productid=0x6387 -usb-passthrough vendorid=0x067b,productid=0x2303
```

Comment: Any update on the issue, it seems changes got merged into emu-master-dev branch?

Comment: Please update on this issue. is it working in windows environment. It seems changes merged into emulator version 31.1.4.

Comment: Yes it seems the usb option is back in the binary, but I can't get any USB device through. Do you have a source for that merge?

Comment: I am not getting usb-host error but I also can't get any USB device through. You can refer this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/refs/heads/emu-31-release/hw/usb/host-libusb.c

Comment: oh great, thanks. This brought up some new tools.

Comment: strange..not working for me, I am trying to pass through FTDI Usb serial device 



emulator Pixel_2_API_24 -usb-passthrough vendorid=0x0403,productid=0x6001



The emulator starts with no error however I my app is unable to list any Usb devices

I also tried



emulator Pixel_2_API_24 -qemu -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=0x0403,productid=0x6001



This also does not list any devices in the UsbManager API